# Not sure why componentWillMount is not updating state

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am using following code to fetch and render data from the published API source but unable to set the state after successfully getting the data on the console. Following is my code;

```
    // ########## Import Dependencies Here ##########
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, ListView, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Dimensions, RefreshControl, Platform } from 'react-native';
    import { Container, Card, CardItem, Content, Left, Right, Icon } from 'native-base';
    import FitImage from 'react-native-fit-image';
    import TimeAgo from 'react-native-timeago';
    import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';

    // ########## Import Screens Here ##########
    import ReadMore from './ReadMore';

    // ########## Import Components Here ##########
    import { contentText, contentURL } from '../helpers/helpers';

    const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

    export default class Home extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          rowData: [],
          isLoading: true,
        }
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        return fetch('https://vinth.azurewebsites.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log('will mount')
            console.log(responseJson);
            console.log('state',this.state);
            let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
              rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
            });
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
            }, function () {
              // do something with new state
            });
            console.log('state',this.state);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <View>
              <StatusBar
                barStyle="light-content"
              />
            </View>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.dataSource}
              renderRow={
                (rowData) =>
                  <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>         this.props.navigation.navigate('ReadMore', { rowData })}>
                      <Card>
                        <CardItem header>
                          <Text style={styles.titleHeading}>{rowData.title.rendered}</Text>
                        </CardItem>
                        <CardItem cardBody>
                          <Content style={styles.cardContainer}>
                            <FitImage
                              source={{ uri: contentURL(rowData.better_featured_image.source_url) }}
                              style={{ width: width, height: 200 }}
                            />
                            <HTML tagsStyles={bodyText} html={contentText(rowData.excerpt.rendered)} />
                          </Content>
                        </CardItem>
                        <CardItem style={styles.borderLine}>
                          <Left>
                          </Left>
                          <Right>
                          </Right>
                        </CardItem>
                      </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
              }
            />
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }
```

Strangely enough the componentWillMount code was working in one of my previously done app in React Native (0.50.0). At the moment I am using React Native 0.53.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, isn't this an expected behavior? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

> therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering

Can't you use `componentDidMount()` instead?

(I know it's RN and not React, but it seems to me some breaking changes happened lately)

Comment: Same results with componentDidMount as well, however what did work for me is following chunk of code, not sure how it is different from my original attempt;

Comment: `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([])
    }
  }`

Comment: `componentWillMount() {
    return fetch('https://vinth.azurewebsites.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // let ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        //   rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        // });
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
        }, function () {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }`